# it is giving segmentation fault . i am trying to implement ford fulkerson algorithm ,here i am reading from file

Tags: c++, ford-fulkerson

```
int main()
{
    int i,j,k,l,m;
    int maxflow=0;
    int first,second,capac;

    int residual[100][100];
    //reading from file
    FILE*fp;
    fp=fopen("ford.txt","r");
    fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&node,&edge);
    cout<<"nodes are"<<node<<"\n"<<"edges are"<<edge<<"\n";
    for(j=1;j<=node;j++)
    {
        for(k=1;k<=node;k++)
        {
            capacity[j][k]=0;
        }  
    }
    for(i=0;i<edge;i++)
    { 
        fscanf(fp,"%d %d %d",&first,&second,&capac);
        cout<<first<<"->"<<second<<"="<<capac<<"\n"; //it is printing this
        capacity[first][second]=capac;//crashes here at last i/p i.e.1=edge-1

    }
    cout<<"abc"; //this is not printed
    for(l=1;l<=node;l++)
    {
        for(m=1;m<=node;m++)
        {
            flow[l][m]=capacity[l][m];
            flow[m][l]=0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is not even printing the "abc" in the cout statement. I am trying to implement the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm. Here I am reading from a file and initializing capacity flow matrices. After that I am calling maxflow function, which I have omitted here.

Comment: You should run this in the debugger to find out which line is causing the seg-fault.

Comment: what is `capacity` ? The terminating conditions on the `for` loops look prime for out of bounds.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: The famous Frequently Pasted Comment? :-)

Comment: cpacity is matrix storing edge weights.what do you mean by prime out of bounds

Comment: Poor braces are feeling lonely, I bet. Everyone else is close to eachother...

Comment: "prime for out of bounds": most of your for-loops are counting from 1 to node (j,k,l,m)

Comment: Your code doesn't show how `capacity` is defined or the value you read into `node`. Writing outside the array bounds is a likely suspect for your segmentation fault.

Comment: i have declared capacity[100][100] matrix and node as a global variable

Comment: @jrok can u plz explain ur comment

Comment: Your coding style, @user1492991, it's hardly readable. Put some whitespace between operators and identifiers, etc...

Comment: Are you certain that the values read into `node`, `first`, and `second` are in the range 0..99? Any other values will cause you to write outside the bounds of the `capacity` array.

Comment: Make sure you flush `std::cout` - use `std::endl` instead of "\n" - otherwise you won't see output that was buffered but not yet output when you crash. And keep in mind that C++ arrays are not one-based, but zero-based.

Comment: for(i=0;i<edge;i++)
    { 
        fscanf(fp,"%d %d %d",&first,&second,&capac);
        cout<<first<<"->"<<second<<"="<<capac<<"\n"; //it is printing this
        capacity[first][second]=capac;
    } i have found that my code crashes while taking last i/p from file in above code due to which i am getting segmentation fault

Comment: but i am not able to understand why it is happening .is there some problem with fscanf() .because earlier it was not giving seg.fault

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, your code is more C than C++. Though (as @jrok commented) things like indentation and spacing could use some improvement, I think a rather larger change would be much more helpful. Instead of packing a bunch of unrelated "stuff" into `main`, you really need/want to split things up into functions (and possibly classes to represent the logical "pieces" in your program.

At least from the looks of things, you might want to start with a `matrix` class with (at least) I/O functions. That should probably use a `std::vector` to store the data, so it can read the size in from the file and then allocate the proper amount of space to hold that data.

```
class matrix { 
    std::vector<int> data;
    size_t rows;
    size_t columns;
public:
    std::istream &read(std::istream &infile);
    std::ostream &write(std::ostream &outfile);
};
```

With a decent definition of a matrix, it appears that most of the code you have right now would come out to something like:

```
std::ifstream in("ford.txt");

matrix capacity;
capacity.read(in); // or `in >> capacity;`

matrix flow = capacity;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking to make sure your array accesses are within the bounds of the arrays. Here is some code which does that. I'm assuming that flow is defined the same as capacity and residual since you didn't provide a definition for it.

Additionally, I've changed the loop indices to start at 0, as arrays in C and C++ are indexed from 0, not 1. If you meant to leave the first row and column of your arrays untouched, then you can change those back and change the `<`s to `<=`s.

Also, I've used std::endl to flush the output buffer. Output buffering could possibly have caused the cout<<"abc" to execute but not output anything if the program crashed soon after executing that statement.

```
#define WIDTH 100
#define HEIGHT 100
int capacity[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
int flow[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
int node, edge;
int main() {
    int maxflow=0;
    int first,second,capac;
    int residual[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
    //reading from file
    FILE*fp;
    fp=fopen("ford.txt","r");
    fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&node,&edge);
    cout<<"nodes are"<<node<<"\n"<<"edges are"<<edge<<"\n";
    //check if node is out of bounds...
    if(node >= WIDTH || node >= HEIGHT) {
        //if it is, warn
        cout<<"Warning: node is at least "
            <<WIDTH<<" or "<<HEIGHT<<"."
            <<std::endl;
    }
    //prevent accessing out-of-bounds locations by comparing
    // xIdx and yIdx against WIDTH and HEIGHT, respectively
    for(int xIdx=0; xIdx < node && xIdx < WIDTH; xIdx++) {
        for(int yIdx=0; yIdx < node && yIdx < HEIGHT; yIdx++) {
            capacity[xIdx][yIdx]=0;
        }  
    }
    for(i=0;i<edge;i++) { 
        fscanf(fp,"%d %d %d",&first,&second,&capac);
        cout<<first<<"->"<<second<<"="<<capac<<"\n";
        if(first < WIDTH && second < HEIGHT) {
            capacity[first][second]=capac;
        }
        //Stop execution if one of first or second is out of bounds
        else {
            cout<<"ERROR: ["<<first<<"]["<<second<<"]"
                <<" not within ["<<WIDTH<<"]["<<HEIGHT<<"]"
                <<std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }
    cout<<"abc"<<std::endl;
    for(int xIdx=0; xIdx < node && xIdx < WIDTH; xIdx++) {
        for(int yIdx=0; yIdx < node && yIdx < HEIGHT; yIdx++) {
            flow[xIdx][yIdx]=capacity[xIdx][yIdx];
            flow[yIdx][xIdx]=0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for(i=0;i<edge;i++) { fscanf(fp,"%d %d %d",&first,&second,&capac); cout<<first<<"->"<<second<<"="<<capac<<"\n"; //it is printing this capacity[first][second]=capac; } i have found that my code crashes while taking last i/p from file in above code due to which i am getting segmentation fault

Comment: but i am not able to understand why it is happening .is there some problem with fscanf() .because earlier it was not giving seg.fault